# Como salgo de la categoría de spam en gmail?

Tags: gmail, email

Buenas.

Alguien sabe a ciencia cierta cómo puedo eliminar la etiqueta de spam que gmail coloca a los correos enviados?. Contextualizo un poco para que me puedan ayudar.

- He probado a ver si mi sitio y mi hosting están en las black list, y
  no lo estan, por ende es personal, **no Gmail ni GSuite.**
- **No enviamos correos basuras. Ni manejamos listas de correo masivo**
- Agregamos el link para dejar de recibir correo de nuestra parte (sugerencia de gmail), aún cuando nuestros destinatarios son principalmente clientes fidelizados.
- Normalizamos la proporción de imágenes y texto en los correos enviados.
- Dejamos de enviar correos en blanco y monosilábicos.
- Cambiamos de servidores dns.
- Agregamos el robot.txt a nuestros dns (Por petición de gmail)
- Barajamos la posibilidad de cambiar de hosting, pero eso no nos asegura en ningún caso el resolver el problema.

Sólo tenemos problemas con Gmail, ya que los correos enviados a otros clientes de correo no tienen problemas, verificado y doble verificado con yahoo, hotmail y otros no tan populares.

Agradeceré cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Actualizado, adjunto encabezado de mail detectado como spam

Delivered-To: usuario_gmail@gmail.com
Received: by 10.74.9.67 with SMTP id 64csp1585680ooa;
        Fri, 8 Sep 2017 05:18:52 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AOwi7QBHkItY++ulLIvGPKO9jMd7uqU4V6vVNXXMaFuood4MBN2kVaeZxq/bqwU0DtAgyxqGKnO/
X-Received: by 10.200.15.210 with SMTP id f18mr3782942qtk.226.1504873132265;
        Fri, 08 Sep 2017 05:18:52 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1504873132; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=XgxbxlR7jnteWA7qC5V21fzwvCYykRJhzcNcuIH3qoKtVtE0GoqvgxmvShzsPKqz9S
         AoO1T1pPaNX8dmlTTkZB2g5XlwJLnKIMq6uMefhcGz3qR4/V9C6AQEatHQhL45A95UlK
         Jh2GlBkasoAbEZZXAOtHz2FruQ0L6U23Knn8CUVYdtaxbKCbg0Wk0U6gJnphqGAi/3zt
         f7FCKz7/MdWEEFFlODn+dcyPXjjdi9sXoNe66gccMIcDe/NqgJ86cZt7zSkWURBMALdF
         z3uI0DO8Lg1uHwaNNO32CB1WGwRD8BBCeU8if4vlv/IjxlTroAywsrEZCmj999um16IH
         gmMg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=disposition-notification-to:content-language:thread-index
         :mime-version:message-id:date:subject:in-reply-to:references:to:from
         :dkim-signature:arc-authentication-results;
        bh=G4FpDUIc3gk186u0NN0g3eHBSXqHzCbic+N0mPNorck=;
        b=doCbIHLxTrdEQmzXrsEwSEDUNK0YWQ2tMtyHiFCN9timf5wu1NDNdN26mrf2peK9z0
         eZksrP0Ue1qVxfYt2p56YpU9rfrKgrl1AZTdywO64J6RsEgmX7wy/wkiFKEEtmJSpgt+
         eJ5V17oP7NJp059IXWFhN3g0ZYaEDULnRxeR2RfgpPmL3FSBif9MWiY3pzwYLfFmatpT
         Gtc+9AbE8Z/QraocySIvOZ49PKTcYrQuYigUce0CiP0FAsu9i9ugB2y53ASjMqvCZSyE
         hcfhcLpBHk/fqaH+Ph85LbpxxIcIkckACDaBY55pV/XuryM4gdM813/y4Itzd5girXoT
         9aJg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gpsdatos.cl header.s=default header.b=jgMWSWDu;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of usuario_mail@gpsdatos.cl designates 200.29.217.229 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=usuario_mail@gpsdatos.cl;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gpsdatos.cl
Return-Path: 
Received: from m229.lxh.cl (srv4.akkuarios.com. [200.29.217.229])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id r15si1895748qte.305.2017.09.08.05.18.51
        for 
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 08 Sep 2017 05:18:52 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of usuario_mail@gpsdatos.cl designates 200.29.217.229 as permitted sender) client-ip=200.29.217.229;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gpsdatos.cl header.s=default header.b=jgMWSWDu;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of usuario_mail@gpsdatos.cl designates 200.29.217.229 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=usuario_mail@gpsdatos.cl;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gpsdatos.cl
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by m229.lxh.cl (Postfix) with ESMTP id 4DF9C8041FAC9 for ; Fri,
  8 Sep 2017 09:18:14 -0300 (CLST)
Authentication-Results: m230.lxh.cl (amavisd-new); dkim=pass (1024-bit key) header.d=gpsdatos.cl
Received: from m229.lxh.cl ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (m230.lxh.cl [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10026) with ESMTP id NlYlDWhrtc9c for ; Fri,
  8 Sep 2017 09:18:14 -0300 (CLST)
Received: from srv2.medianetworks.cl (srv2.medianetworks.cl [200.27.67.83]) by m229.lxh.cl (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 0FC408041FAC8 for ; Fri,
  8 Sep 2017 09:18:14 -0300 (CLST)
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by srv14.snh.cl (Postfix) with ESMTP id 0A78A26400B2 for ; Fri,
  8 Sep 2017 09:18:50 -0300 (CLST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=gpsdatos.cl; h= content-language:x-mailer:content-type:content-type:mime-version :message-id:date:date:subject:subject:in-reply-to:references :from:from; s=default; t=1504873129; x=1506687529; bh=8EqNDJFtSr Au9CEgoe/raGc2ghaY8+EG4uSD2Rl268Q=; b=jgMWSWDuTkqkZHW1Ijaa4rhNzO RLbJG2YBBdp3VSx2IcY/gJftXBgC+JQoTfsSwSHbZ6uqTm/T6QCHbvh5l79G+BpU couyJl3iF9ZG2H3E7l9CL9CGecVLOhUMhgGaDyvL4kYCZj3E4fMjb8z+4GkynZwz 2k1h9ktjuUWOnOpEc=
Received: from srv14.snh.cl ([200.27.67.87]) by localhost (isp.lxh.cl [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10026) with ESMTP id kflP0GuetRB1 for ; Fri,
  8 Sep 2017 09:18:49 -0300 (CLST)
Received: from GordoPc (186-107-10-164.baf.movistar.cl [186.107.10.164]) (Authenticated sender: usuario_mail@gpsdatos.cl) by srv14.snh.cl (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 21D2126400C5 for ; Fri,
  8 Sep 2017 09:18:46 -0300 (CLST)
From: "José Pacheco Chávez" 
To: 
References: 
In-Reply-To: 
Subject: RV: lista de materiales
Date: Fri, 8 Sep 2017 09:18:46 -0300
Message-ID: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0000_01D32883.79E84B90"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 16.0
Thread-Index: AdMmd8G4HnsCRi/XSLGlNhSXHYd/mQAACuMQAIkmw2A=
Content-Language: es-cl
Disposition-Notification-To: José Pacheco Chávez

Comment: ¿Tienes cuenta de GSuite (antiguo Google Apps) y por tanto tu correo tiene la extensión de `tuempresa.com` o es un correo con extensión `gmail.com`? ¿Haces envío de correo masivo mediante listas de distribución? Son datos importantes que deberían constar en la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero lo que acotas ya estaba descrito, de todas formas, cambié la redacción para su mejor comprensión.

Comment: Amigo ¿seguro que ese mensaje estaba en la carpeta spam?  Dice que ha pasado el spf , el dmarc, etc. Si estaba en la carpeta spam debe ser a un filtro tuyo personalizado de gmail, el mensaje no fue tratado nunca como spam por Gmail directamente.

Comment: Lamentablemente si, y por eso pregunto acá, ya que supero todos mis conocimientos, la leyenda que muestra gmail dice: _¿Por qué está este mensaje en la carpeta de spam? Hemos detectado que gpsdatos.cl envía mucho correo basura.  Más información_ y sólo enviamos a clientes.

Comment: Quizá alguien está enviando correo con tu dominio. [Revisa esto](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2696779?hl=es)

Answer (score 0):

De entrada te diré que no es una pregunta fácil de responder, ya que intervienen muchos factores.

Al añadirse el que no estés usando GSuite, la solución es más complicada. No sé si por una especie de *presión diplomática* los filtros de spam funcionan muy mal cuando uno tiene un dominio propio y no pasa por GSuite, de pago, o por algún filtro de spam ofrecido por el mismo hosting (yo tengo la impresión de que son servicios algo mediocres), también de pago.

Con esta respuesta quiero ofrecer algunos elementos de análisis que podrían ayudarte a dar con el problema primero, y luego con la solución.

### ¿Qué está ocurriendo con el mensaje?

Es importante comprender lo que está ocurriendo con el mensaje, es decir, **¿por qué ha sido marcado como spam**?

Esa información aparece en el código fuente del mensaje.

Te muestro parte de la información relevante al respecto de un mensaje de mi carpeta spam:

No muy lejos del principio podrías ver algo como esto:

> spf=fail (google.com: domain of preventdementia@moveaart.stream does
>   not designate 74.220.220.119 as permitted sender)
>   smtp.mailfrom=preventdementia@moveaart.stream

**`spf-fail`**  es una información muy importante, significa que ese mensaje ha violado el protocolo spf.

Si está ocurriendo eso, deberás cambiar algunas configuraciones en el DNS de tu hosting.

Si este es el problema, puedes ver:

- [Acerca de los registros SPF](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=es)
- [El protocolo SPF, un aliado para luchar contra el spam](https://blog.mailrelay.com/es/2012/01/23/el_protocolo_spf_un_aliado_para_luchar_contra_el_spam)

Y tendrías que informarte sobre la forma exacta de configurar dicho protocolo en la configuración de tu dominio, según el hosting que tengas. Aunque la forma de hacerlo es casi siempre la misma.

Luego, siguiendo con el código fuente del mensaje, podrías ver cosas como estas:

> ```
> X-Spam-Status: No, score=2.5
> X-Spam-Score: 25
> X-Spam-Bar: ++
> X-Ham-Report: Spam detection software, running on the system "*****.bluehost.com", has NOT identified this incoming email as spam.
>   The original message has been attached to this so you can view it or label similar future email.
>   If you have any questions, see root\@localhost for details.
>   Content preview:
>   Prevent Dementia By Simply Eating The Right Foods See Which
>     Ones. http://www.moveaart.stream/l/lt12CC9018VC342C/354JM2011I194745RG370YD41664033J758873973
>     http://www.moveaart.stream/unsL9018BJ342W/354WG2011F194745JW370D41664033K758873973
>     [...]
>    Content analysis details:
>    (2.5 points, 3.0 required)
>    pts rule name
>               description ---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
>   0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED
>           ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was blocked.
>                              See
>                              http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
>                               for more information.
>                              [URIs: moveaart.stream] -0.5 SPF_PASS
>                SPF: sender matches SPF record
>   0.0 WEIRD_QUOTING
>           BODY: Weird repeated double-quotation marks
>   0.0 HTML_MESSAGE
>            BODY: HTML included in message
>   3.0 RDNS_NONE
>               Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS
> X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
> X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - ****.bluehost.com
> X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - midominio.org
> X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
> X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - moveaart.stream
> X-BWhitelist: no
> X-Source-IP: 45.59.127.117
> X-Exim-ID: 1dq47h-000h2u-3V
> X-Source: 
> X-Source-Args: 
> X-Source-Dir: 
> X-Source-Sender: (027be15b.moveaart.stream) [45.59.127.117]:53761
> X-Source-Auth: tuusuariodehosting
> X-Email-Count: 1
> X-Source-Cap: ZGVpdmVyYnU7ZGVpdmVyYnU7Ym94OTUwLmJsdWVob3N0LmNvbQ==
> X-Local-Domain: no
> X-Forwarder: ***.bluehost.com
> ```

Si hay datos de esta naturaleza o parecidos podrás comprender lo que Google piensa de los mensajes que se están enviando desde tu correo electrónico.

Quizá Google no te dará un trato tan severo como en este caso, ya que el encabezado que he escogido para la respuesta es el de un mensaje enviado por un spammer de verdad... y tú no lo eres.

---

#### Trabajar en una solución

De acuerdo a los encabezados que veas en tus mensajes tratados como spam, podrás entonces actual en consecuencia.

Es posible que necesites:

- Configurar un SPF (Sender Policy Framework). Sería algo así más o menos:

  ```
     example.com   TXT     v=spf1 a ~all
  ```
- Configurar DKIM records. Algo así más o menos:

  ```
     selector1._domainkey.example.com        TXT     k=rsa;p=J8eTBu224i086iK
  ```
- Configurar DMARC records. Algo así más o menos:

  ```
      _dmarc.example.com   TXT     v=DMARC1;p=none;sp=quarantine;pct=100;rua=mailto:dmarcreports@example.com
  ```

> **Nota:** Para hacer esto necesitas imperativamente consultar la ayuda de tu hosting, ya que un registro mal configurado podría hacer que el
>   email o todo el dominio dejen de funcionar.

Comment: Estimado, los registros SPF, DKIM Y DMARC estan ok,                         
SPF: PASS con la IP 200.29.217.229
DKIM: PASS 
DMARC: PASS

Comment: @JoséPepoCachoChávez ¿podrías poner en la pregunta los encabezados de uno de los mensajes tratado como spam (tomados desde Gmail), sin revelar los datos personales del mensaje? Ahí debe decir el motivo .

Comment: Información solicitada agregada, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si entraste a la lista negra de Gmail o algún otro seguramente fue por:

1. Mandas muchos mails
2. Varios usuarios marcaron tus correos como spam
3. Alguien puso tu nombre de dominio en alguna lista negra de la cual Gmail toma información

Para solucionarlo tienes que reportarlo a google en este enlace: https://support.google.com/mail/contact/msgdelivery

Si todo va bien en "algún tiempo" volverán tus correos a la normalidad

Comment: Gracias, estoy llenando el formulario y a esperar a ver que dicen, tengo claro que puede pasar un mes antes que respondan.

Comment: Si, he escuchado casos de dos semanas hasta dos meses. Asi que ha esperar