# mail() no envía los correos desde mi servidor pero sí desde mi localhost

Tags: php

He creado una pequeña aplicación que pide unos datos al cliente, al ingresarlos y pulsar el botón, se hace un INSERT en la base de datos con dichos datos, y si el resultado de la query devuelve true, muestro una notifiación al cliente y además envío un correo (con la función mail() de PHP) a este.

Ahora bien, todo el código parece estar perfectamente, porque si lo envío desde mi aplicación en localhost (uso Fake Sendmail version 32), sí que lo recibo en mi cuenta de Gmail y además, en mi bandeja de entrada (nada de que me llega a SPAM), pero si, con exactamente la misma aplicación (todo el código es igual, un copia y pega), lo trato de hacer en el servidor que tengo, todo funciona perfectamente salvo el MAIL(), que a Gmail no se envia (ni a la bandeja de entrada ni a la de SPAM), mientras que si pongo mi correo de hotmail sí que me llega, pero en este caso, a la bandeja de SPAM.

Es decir, yo tengo dos entornos de trabajo:

-> Mi servidor local (localhost), en el que todo funciona perfectamente.

-> Mi servidor ajeno en el cual todo funciona menos el mail().

He de decir, que tengo dos aplicaciones (no tienen nada que ver, pero como está el mail() configurado en ambas es idéntico), una que hasta hace unos días funcionaba todo perfectamente en el servidor, pero que justamente hoy ha decidido fallar, y otra, esta de la que he hablado, sólo me ha funcionado en local.

He comprobado los logs por si el email no se envíaba por algún error de función o lo que sea y todo parece estar bien (repito, en hotmail sí que llega, pero a la bandeja de SPAM).

El código es el siguiente (dónde $resultado es el booleano que genera como resultado la query del INSERT de los datos en la base de datos):

```
if ( $resultado ) {
                    $para = $email;
                    $titulo = 'Información';
                    $mensaje = 'Aquí tienes todos los datos que puedes necesitar. ¡Muchas gracias por confiar en nosotros! <br>
                                <a href=\"localhost/salva/includes/pdf/pdf.pdf\">Descargar PDF</a>';
                    mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje);
                    echo "¡Se le han enviado los datos a su correo electrónico correctamente!";
                }
```

¿Alguna idea? He leído cosas de los headers, pero el problema es que en la aplicación antigua, la función del email es casi idéntica y hasta hace unos días funcionaba perfectamente, pero casualmente, hoy no.

Comment: Cuando se envían correos desde el servidor debes seguir una serie de pasos que ahora no recuerdo para evitar que esos envíos sean clasificados como spam. Hay una configuración `DKIM` (me parece que se llama así) y otra SPFS o algo así, hay que configurar uno de los DNS que tampoco recuerdo ahora. Puede que si has enviado registros masivos Google te haya metido en una lista negra o algo así. Si revisas el código fuente del mensaje podrás ver que pruebas aprobó el mensaje y que pruebas suspendió... [Aquí respondí algo sobre el tema hace tiempo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/100712/29967)

Comment: Verifica si tenes el stmp-server, y si es asi vas al archivo php.ini y modificas
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = aqui pones el email a donde quieres que lleguen los mesajes. Por otro aldo algunos proveedores de hosting pueden desabilitar esa opcion por lo que podes usar librerias como PHPmailer para poder enviar correos. Aca tenes un ejemplo de como usarlo https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/214518/3092 uniendolo con plantillas de foundation y con alertas de sweetalert

Comment: ¿En el de hotmail? Porque en Gmail es imposible. Desde el servidor a Gmail no me llega ni a bandeja de entrada ni a SPAM. Lo miraré en hotmail a ver. Y respecto a lo de la lista negra, es posible, hice un par de pruebas pero nada masivo... Y ahora estoy mirando y creo que me he explicado mal. Editaré mi post, lo que quería decir es que el cleinte recibe un correo, no yo, es decir, el que rellenó el formulario recibe un correo con datos. Miraré esto que me habéis dicho. Gracias!

Comment: En gmail para que puedas mandar mails desde uno de estos correos tenes que habilitar la opcion (o deshabilitar no me acuerdo) de que se use con aplicaciones menos seguras: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=es-419

Comment: No, a ver. El correo se envía al cliiente desde una dirección de correo del propio servidor (no desde Gmail ni desde una dirección @gmail.com).

Comment: el hosting debe tener sendmail configurado para usar un relay que puede estar en lista negra, fijate el código fuente del mail que te llega a spam para verificarlo ( abrís el mail ... mas opciones -> origen del mensaje) . sospecho que en local el fake sendmail lo envía directo (via smtp) por eso pasa los filtros. comparando ambos codigo fuente podes comprobarlo