# ¿Como evitar que mi correo llegue como SPAM? en C#

Tags: c#, email

Tengo el siguiente correo, en el cual incluyo imagen, pero llegan siempre a la carpeta spam:

```
 public Respuesta enviaCorreo(string email_cliente, string email_envio, string passEnvio, string smtp, int puerto, string nropedido,
        string nombrecliente, string emaildestinatario, DataTable productos, DataTable Direccioncliente)
    {
        Respuesta resp = new Respuesta();
        try
        {
            string titulo_subjet_contacto = "[titulo] Nuevo pedido #(" + nropedido + ")";
            DateTime fecha_actual = DateTime.Now;
            string mes_str = MonthName(fecha_actual.Month);
            string fecha = fecha_actual.Day.ToString() + " de " + mes_str + " del " + fecha_actual.Year.ToString();
            double precio_item = 0;
            double valor_despacho = 0;
            double total = 0;
            double descuento = 0;
            var folder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/img/favicon.png");
            var folder_transferencia = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/img/transferencia.jpg");



            string body = "<center><IMG id='idp' border='0' alt='idp' src='cid:idp' width='94' height='94'></center>";
            body = body + "<p>Has recibido el siguiente pedido de : " + nombrecliente + "</p>";
            body = body + "<p>[Pedido #" + nropedido + "] (" + fecha + ")</p>";
            body = body + "<p></p>";
            
            body = body + "<br/>Felicidades por su pedido<br/>";
            body = body + "<br/><IMG id='transferencia' border='0' alt='idp' src='cid:transferencia'><br/>";

            MailMessage mensaje = new MailMessage(email_cliente, email_cliente);
            mensaje.Subject = titulo_subjet_contacto;
            mensaje.Bcc.Add(emaildestinatario);//revisador pedido
            string textBody = body;
            AlternateView plainTextView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(textBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

            string htmlBody = "<html><body>" + textBody + "</body></html>";
            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

            string imagePathF =folder;//aqui la ruta de tu imagen
            LinkedResource face = new LinkedResource(imagePathF);
            face.ContentId = "idp";
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(face);

            string imagePathTra = folder_transferencia;//aqui la ruta de tu imagen
            LinkedResource transf = new LinkedResource(imagePathTra);
            transf.ContentId = "transferencia";
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(transf);
            mensaje.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

            // Definir el servidor SMTP, GMail usa SSL para la autenticación
            SmtpClient smtp_host = new SmtpClient(smtp, puerto);
            smtp_host.EnableSsl = true;

            // Ingresar nuestra cuenta de gmail
            smtp_host.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email_envio, passEnvio);
            smtp_host.Send(mensaje);

            resp.retorno = 1;
            resp.mensaje = "Correo enviado exitosamente";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resp.retorno = -3;
            resp.mensaje = ex.Message;

        }

        return resp;
    }
```

Al parecer el problema radica al usar AlternateView, pero es la única forma que se hasta ahora, si alguien tiene alguna idea o ejemplo, se lo agradecería mucho.

Saludos a todos, espero su buen aporte.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100699/como-salgo-de-la-categor%c3%ada-de-spam-en-gmail?rq=1

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero yo creo que es porque estoy usando AlternateView, ya que de la forma anterior no me pasaba, las imagenes las detecta como spam, quizas exista otra forma de colocar imagen en el cuerpo del correo

Comment: En mi caso he intentado 3 cosas diferentes en el pasado, y el resultado siempre el mismo, caigo a la carpeta de spam. En algún momento u otro, ya sea masivo o pocos. Pero si aparece alguien que sepa la solución, quedaré al pendiente.